# What are the best practices for creating email addresses on a domain and its subdomains?

Tags: email, best-practices, email-address

I want to setup several applications on my own server, both having their subdomain.
Until now, I had one generic email address `generic@example.com` for every purpose.
I think this is a bad design, so I decided to implement it in a more hierarchical way with email redirections such as below :

```
+-- admin@example.com                     --> host administration
|   |
|   +-- webmaster@example.com             --> RFC 2142, really needed ?
|   |
|   +-- test@example.com                  --> dev & tests
|   |
|   +-- logs.server@example.com           --> server error logs
|   |
|   +-- logs.crontab@example.com          --> crontab error logs
|   |
|   \-- logs.appname@example.com          --> app logs...
|
+-- contact@example.com                   --> contact with users
|   |
|   +-- notifications@example.com         --> automatic emails to users
|   |
|   \-- notifications.appname@example.com --> or should I be more specific ?
|
\-- username@example.com                  --> user emails...
```

Should I use one dedicated email address for each purpose and/or each app ?

Should I define email addresses for subdomains ? `purpose.appname@example.com` vs `purpose@appname.example.com` ?

Do you have any advice, best practices, examples ?

Comment: "Should I use one dedicated email address for each purpose and/or each app ?" This is mostly a business/non-technical question. So both cases work, what is best in your situation, only you can say. Same for "purpose.appname@example.com vs purpose@appname.example.com" it is mostly a matter of taste. In the webworld it can have an impact (due to cookie handling), but less so in email world, as long as you are not too deep in SPF/DKIM/DMARC stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought there were maybe technical pros/cons to define too much generic vs too much specific email addresses. Which convention do you use ?